# Page loads with dynamic route look same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm making a customizable set of form pages; driven by a DB.

I build each `QuestionPage` component from json data pulled from a DB... using the current pathname to get the appropriate Data.

My route looks like this:

```
<Switch> 
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>HOME</h1>} />
        {this.state.navMenu}
        <Route path="/Dashboard" render={() => <Dashboard appBarTextCB={this.setAppBarText} text="Dashboard" navControl={this.navigationControl}/>} />  
        <Route path="/:pageName" render={() => <QuestionPage appBarTextCB={this.setAppBarText} tabName={this.props.location.pathname.slice(1)} navControl={this.navigationControl}/>} />
        <Route render={() => <ErrorPage errMsg="Route was not found" appBarTextCB={this.setAppBarText}  navControl={this.navigationControl}/>} />
</Switch>
```

If I go to domain.com/XYZ I get the appropriate XYZ 'page'. Yay.  If I then use my nav menu to go to domain.com/ABC I still see the XYZ information. Boo.

If I then actively type in the URL of the ABC page (or hit refresh when I'm on the page) I see the correct ABC information.

If I use the navigation menu to go to one of the non-dynamic routes, say domain.com/Dashboard and then to ABC... I get the ABC page.  If I then use the navigation menu to go to XYZ, the ABC page remains.

I will note I've put console.log's in the QuestionPage lifecycles... and when using the nav menu, those logs come through with the information I hope to recieve.

I'm kind of at a loss... my best guess is that the `Router` is only creating one component (and I'm looking for a new, referencable, component with each new url)  - which isn't being updated with the navigation menu.

So my question is:  How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that a new component is not mounted when `:pageName` changes. You could take out the `match` route prop from the function given to `render` and pass that down as a prop to the `QuestionPage` component, and check if the `pageName` URL parameter changes, and reload your data if it does.

**The `Route`**

```
<Route
  path="/:pageName"
  render={({ match }) => (
    <QuestionPage
      match={match}
      appBarTextCB={this.setAppBarText}
      tabName={this.props.location.pathname.slice(1)}
      navControl={this.navigationControl}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

**QuestionPage.js**

```
class QuestionPage {
  getData = pageName => {
    // ...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(this.props.match.params.pageName);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.pageName !== this.props.match.params.pageName) {
      this.getData(this.props.match.params.pageName);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept - thank you, very helpful.
Question about "Take the match route" syntax you used here.  Do you have a reference where I could learn more about what you did there?

Comment: @lowcrawler You're welcome! It's called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Instead of writing `render={(props) => ...}` and use `props.match`, you can destructure it `render={({ match }) => ...}` so you can use `match` straight away.